# PHP While() Stop Looping

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php loop which displays only one record even if there is hundreds.

here is the code:

```
<?php

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die(mysql_error());  
$numexem = mysql_num_rows($result1);
$s="0";

while($s<$numexem){
$postid=mysql_result($result1,$s,"id");
echo "Post id:".$postid;

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pics WHERE postid='$postid'") or die(mysql_error());  
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result2) or die(mysql_error());
$pnum = mysql_num_rows($result2);

echo " There is ".$pnum." Attached Pictures";

$s++;
}

?>
```

I'm wondering if the loop stop because there is other SQL query inside it or what?
and i don't think so.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a more traditional approach:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die(mysql_error());  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
  ...
}
```

Also, don't do all these subordinate queries. Instead:

```
$sql = <<<END
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pics WHERE postid = p.postid) pic_count
FROM posts p
END;
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . ': ' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  echo "$row[postid] has $row[pic_count] pictures\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. By default, the MySQL PHP module prefetches all rows that match your query, so there's nothing to worry about in your code.

However, executing a hundred query can be time-consuming. You'd rather collect all the IDs from your first loop, then perform *one* single query using the SQL `IN` operator and get these results after. Avoid "nesting" queries as much as you can.